# How to run a .SQL File in Amazon RDS MySql databse using shell script

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have one SQL file that contains one query to create a table in AWS RDS MySQL database and I want to do this using shell script.

Here the problem is, I don't know how to do this, can anybody please share the steps?

Please help!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? If you get errors running the SQL Query please add the sql statement to the question so we can help you.

Comment: I do not know how to write shell script that will run my .sql file in amazon rds MySQL database.

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html

Comment: I want one shell script that should be able to connect with aws MySQL database and create one table in database, please tell me how to write that shell script file.